# Nging redirection for multiple sites without using IF

Tags: nginx, system-administration

This is my current WORKING nginx configuration that eliminates the WWW for every request that contains them. I would like a configuration that works the same without using IF statement.

any ideas?

```
server {
   listen  888.888.888.456:80;
   charset utf-8;
   root    "/home/app/root/";
   server_name ~^(.+)$;
   if ($http_host ~ "www.(.*)") {
     return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri;
   }
   index index.php;

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
       include       fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV production;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would involve the creation of a server {} for the www and non-www respectively.

```
sudo vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf

server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

and you use the working for the non-www and remove the if.

Source: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#server-name-if

Comment: How do I change: server_name ~^(.+)$;  into a reg_exp that will only grab the domains that start with www ?